# Is $this->session->userdata and $this->session->has_userdata same when use for authenticate in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I used use following code to authenticate in CodeIgniter.

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))){
        redirect(base_url());
}
```

After reading the documentation again I found the Codeigniter has another function for it.

```
if(!($this->session->has_userdata('user_id'))){
            redirect(base_url());
}
```

If both codes are same or my code has security issues?

Answer (score 1):

**Both are different functions & both of them have their own usage.**

> The second is better option to use because it checks whether the `user_data` has `user_id` key or not & thus runs on less code (but it is a legacy function you should use `isset($_SESSION[$key])` instead of it).

the first one :-

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('user_id'))){
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

It access the value of `user_id` key in `userdata` array in `session` array.

And the second one :-

```
if(!($this->session->has_userdata('user_id'))){
        redirect(base_url());
}
```

It checks whether the `user_id` key exists or not.

**NOTE:**

> `has_userdata($key)` is a legacy method kept only for backwards compatibility with older applications. It is just an alias for `isset($_SESSION[$key])` - please use that instead.
>
> It returns TRUE if the specified key exists, FALSE if not

Comment: So why do you said the second is better? because as you said,  even `user_id =0` or `user_id =""`that function return true???? But my function return false... It is good, isn't it?

Comment: You are not correct in saying "It access the value of `user_id` key in `userdata` array in `session` array without checking for it's existence in the array" . It does check and returns NULL if the `$key` does not exist in `$_SESSION`

Comment: @DamithRuwan, The second executes slightly less code than the first. In fact the code for `has_userdata($key)` is one line of code - `return isset($_SESSION[$key]);` Which is why the documentation recommends you simply use that one line instead of calling the session method.

Comment: @DFriend It doesn't checks, it returns NULL because there is no value associated with that key in `userdata` array

Comment: If it doesn't check how does it know to return NULL? Go look at the source code and stop making uninformed statements.

Comment: @DFriend the source says : "The userdata() method returns NULL if the item you are trying to access does not exist.", It never states about checking it.

Comment: @ManishYadav Again I ask you, How does it know to return NULL if it does not check for the existence of the item? Again, look at the source code. The first line in the `userdata` method is `if(isset($key)) Is that not checking that the key exists?

Comment: @DFriend OK, I guess you are right. Thanks for correcting my mistake