# My session doesnot work properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-session

I have the problem, that the following `if` condition always goes into the first `if` condition, never into the `elseif` condition.

This is my code below :

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('role') == 1) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('adashboard');    
} elseif ($this->session->has_userdata('role') == 2) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('udashboard');
}
```

Can you tell my why?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Is $this->session->userdata and $this->session->has_userdata same when use for authenticate in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411551/is-this-session-userdata-and-this-session-has-userdata-same-when-use-for-a)

Comment: You have same code for if and else

Comment: @NadunKulatunge He redirects to two different pages.

Comment: Like mentioned in the accepted answer of the question that @GolezTrol linked in his comment, the function `has_userdata()` just returns a `bool` that indicates whether or not the key exist, not the value behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use `userdata` instead of `has_userdata` : `userdata` returns Value of the specified item key*

```
if ($this->session->userdata('role') == 1) 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('adashboard');    
} 
elseif ($this->session->userdata('role') == 2) 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('udashboard');
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Totaly I did that just after posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you**

has_userdata() check whether given session index is set or not and it return boolen value.

```
$this->session->has_userdata('role') ;
```

this code check whether role is set or not. So in your case it returns true that's equivalent to 1.

In your case you need to use `userdata()` instead of `has_userdata()`.

```
$role=$this->session->userdata('role');
if ($role == 1) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('adashboard');    
} elseif ($role == 2) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome ' . $userInfo[0]->name . '!');
    redirect('udashboard');
}
```